# Treat radio group as a single element for purposes of Tab order

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, radio-button

I have a 3 `RadioButton`s which represent 3 options (call them A, B, C) that can be selected for a single decision. On the window there are other controls, such as a button and text box.

When I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate between controls, it first goes to A, then B, then C.

Since the user can already navigate between the `RadioButton`s using the arrow keys, I don't want <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get bogged down with iterating over all 3 radios. Instead, when the user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the control immediately preceding the radio group, focus should switch to one of the radio buttons. If he presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, instead of switching to the next radio button, it should go to whatever element follows the radio group in tab order.

How can I do this? Can I do it with only XAML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TabNavigation` attached property in this way:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel Margin="4">
        <TextBox Margin="3" TabIndex="1" />
        <ItemsControl IsTabStop="false" Margin="3" TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once">   
            <RadioButton Content="A" Margin="1" />
            <RadioButton Content="B" Margin="1" />
            <RadioButton Content="C" Margin="1" />
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBox Margin="3" TabIndex="3" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Is it what you meant?

Comment: @VarlainSystems, happy to have been helpful!